# How to setup hot-reload in react.js using VS Code devcontainers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm starting to learn react. My usual setup is VS Code with Docker-based devcontainers. I used create-react-app to create a really simple app I can play around with. But somehow hot reload doesn't work. Any ideas what the problem could be?

For now, I use a really basic Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.0
```

My .devcontainer is also really simple

```
{
"name": "Try React",
"dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
"runArgs": ["-u", "node"],
}
```

The console of my browser displays

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..
```

as expected.
But when I save files nothing happens.

Comment: I wouldn't use Docker here.  Just install Node directly on the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze okay, interesting. Could you explain that a bit more. Based on which factors would you decide to use or not use Docker in a project?

Answer (score 2):

Add the flag **CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true** so file changes are detected inside the container.

You can either;

- `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npm run start` from the command line
- add `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to a .env file in your project root folder
- `export CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` as an environment variable
- `"start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start"` to your package.json

This worked for me in a vscode devcontainer using bullseye and React 17

Comment: If CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true doesn't work, use WATCHPACK_POLLING=true instead. I'm currently using create-react-app where the provided React is 18 but it's probably got to do with the webpack or react-scripts being used by create-react-app rather than the React 18.